# How can I iterate over DomCrawler results and search for specific elements

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

Consider a webpage with multiple divs with class `day`. I have a list of those divs thanks to [DOMCrawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$days = $crawler->filter('.day');
```

Those `day` divs contain an array, and I need to iterate over each row, and then each cell. In theory, I would want to do the following:

```
foreach($days as $day) {
    $rows = $day->filter('tr');
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $cells = $row->filter('td');
        foreach($cells as $cell) {
            echo ($cell->textContent);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to that correctly.

Comment: When iterating over results you don't get a `Crawler` but a `Node`, you have to reinstantiate a new crawler in each one to use crawler functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need those nested loops:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$cells = $crawler->filter('.day td');
$cells->each(function (Crawler $cell) {
    dump($cell->text());
});
```

with nested loops like in your example

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$days = $crawler->filter('.day');
$days->each(function (Crawler $day) {
    $rows = $day->filter('tr');
    $rows->each(function (Crawler $row) {
        $cells = $row->filter('td');
        $cells->each(function (Crawler $cell) {
            dump($cell->text());
        });
    });
});
```